# How to refer to the returned type

Tags: spring

I want to create a spring bean as below.

```
  <bean id="qNameString" class="javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants.STRING"/>
```

Here I want the reference to return type which is a QName but I understand the way I referred is wrong. Can someone please help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring can create a QName for you like this:

```
<bean id="qName" class="java.xml.namespace.QName">
   <constructor index="0" value="localpart"/>
   <constructor index="1" value="namespaceURI"/>
</bean>
```

Replace `localpart` and `namespaceURI` with the local name and namespace.

To reference a constant in a class, like `javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants.STRING`

```
<bean id="qNameString" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetField" value="javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants.STRING"/>
</bean>
```

A shorter version is available with the `util` schema:

```
<util:constant static-field="java.xml.xpath.XPathConstants.STRING"/>
```

Apart from being shorter, the `id` of the bean will be `java.xml.xpath.XPathConstants.STRING` rather than `qNameString`.

See [FieldRetrievingFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/FieldRetrievingFactoryBean.html) and [The util schema](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util)

Answer (score 1):

That won't work, because `class="javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants.STRING"` makes no sense, since what you're referring to isn't a class.

You can refer to static fields using `<util:constant>`, as documented [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util):

```
<property name="...">
   <util:constant static-field="javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants.STRING"/>
</property>
```